# NativeScript app.start does not fire page events

Tags: nativescript

I'm seeing a strange behavior with my simple NativeScript / Typescript app.  In the app.ts i launch the application like so:

```
app.start({ moduleName: "pages/home/home-page" });
```

but debug break points in home-page.ts in the loaded and navigatingTo event handlers don't stop execution.  however when in the app i click on the Home page link the events are fired and the break points are stopped.  So it looks like the app.start call does not fire page lifecycle events at all.
Seems like a strange behavior.  Any ides?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the application is being executed too fast and the debugger doesn't have time to attach.  To fix this problem in the launch.json (debugger configuration in VSC) set

```
"stopOnEntry": true
```

This will stop the application on the first line and allow time for the debugger to attach.